# Why can't I get Angular Xeditable to work live on my Heroku site?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, heroku, x-editable

I'm trying to understand why angular xeditable isn't working on my heroku app. The example I have works locally but not live, so I'm scratching my head trying to understand why.

It should work just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/25/ . When you click on the text, it allows you to edit inline and save changes.

But when I click on the link to the text, nothing happens. The url of the present page just changes to have a # appended to the end

I've installed angular-xeditable using 'npm install angular-xeditable@0.1.12' in my project directory

Here are the files:

dashboard.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<% include ../partials/header.ejs %>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<% include ../partials/nav.ejs %>
<div class = "jumbotron">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>   
</div>
    <div class="dashboard">
    <div class="container" style="background-color: white !important"> 
    <h4>Angular-xeditable Text (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
      <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <a href="#" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
   editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user'
};
});
```

Comment: any console error messages ?